# Database for ios, android and windows?

Tags: android, iphone, ios, windows

I am planning to develop an app. This app needs to integrate/interface with a website i.e. the data is common for both the app and the website. In future I have to release the same app in Android and in Windows Mobile also. So please help by answering below questions

1) Is it possible to have common database for ios, android, windows and a website?
2) Which is the database I should use so that it is common for app, android,windows and website

Please help. Please let me know if my question is not clear.

Thanks in adv.

Comment: On device (Application) side **SQLIteDB** and at Server side **MySQL, SQl or any** you can use...

Comment: if you are using webservice then ofcourse you can use a single db thats in the webside android uses SQLite for db but if data is from web you can use json or xml to transfer data b/w and invoke db from webside

Comment: I need to feed the videos into the database and embed these videos to relevent item is it possible using Sqlite?